# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named " "

Tags: python, django, module, settings

Here is the context:
I am working on Django. I started coding features but stopped to set up the first unit tests.

I wanted to test my CustomUser class located in JoBooking.models.py in the test_models.py file. JoBooking is an app I created in my Django project.

So I did the import from JoParis.JoBookings.models import CustomUser.

When I run python manage.py test or pytest in the terminal, I encounter this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoParis.JoBooking'

I have configured the application (JoBooking) in settings.py... but nothing works.

The init.py files are present in the packages.

I did a simple test to check if the URL of my application returns an HTTP 200 response, and the test works, but I have to remove the import from JoParis.JoBookings.models import CustomUser. So the test file is found, but the problem comes from the import when I want to test my models.

I'm stuck. I don't understand this error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named     Just explain me what is this error please. Thanks

In test_models.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from ...JoBooking.models import CustomUser


# test inscription avec données valides et obligatoires
class TestCreateUser(TestCase):
    def test_create_user(self):
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
            email='usertest@mail.com',
            password='password',
            username='',
            first_name='user',
            last_name='test',
            is_superuser=False,
            is_staff=False
        )
        assert CustomUser.objects.filter(email='usertest@mail.com').exists()  # verifie si dans la BDD
        assert user.first_name == 'user'
        assert user.last_name == 'test'
        assert user.is_superuser is False  # verifie si attribut par défaut pris en compte
        assert user.is_staff is False


# test inscription  avec données non valides
# test connexion user avec True data
# test connexion user avec False data


# test qui verifie  http response = 200
class TestUrl(TestCase):
    def test_my_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

in setting.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = x

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'JoBooking',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'JoParis.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "JoBooking/templates/JoBooking")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'JoParis.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "read_default_file": 'C:\\Users\\murhe\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\EXAM JO\\my.cnf.txt',
        },
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'JoBooking.CustomUser'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'JoBooking.authbackends.EmailAuthBackend',
]
```

The error message

```
: (venv) PS C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis> pytest
====================================================================== test session starts =======================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-8.0.1, pluggy-1.4.0
django: version: 5.0.2, settings: JoParis.settings (from ini)
rootdir: C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-4.8.0
collected 0 items / 2 errors                                                                                                                                      

============================================================================= ERRORS ============================================================================= 
________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting JoBooking/tests/test_models.py _________________________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis\JoBooking\tests\test_models.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoParis.JoBooking'
_________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting JoBooking/tests/test_views.py _________________________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis\JoBooking\tests\test_views.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoParis.JoBooking'
======================================================================== warnings summary ======================================================================== 
..\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:1396
  C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:1396: PytestConfigWarning: Unknown config option: PYTHONPATH       

    self._warn_or_fail_if_strict(f"Unknown config option: {key}\n")

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
==================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================== 
ERROR JoBooking/tests/test_models.py
ERROR JoBooking/tests/test_views.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 2 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
================================================================== 1 warning, 2 errors in 0.68s ===============
```

in views.py
'''

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from .forms import Connexion
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser, Offre, Reservation, Commande
from .authbackends import EmailAuthBackend
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
import uuid

# méthode pour créer un formulaire d'inscription (utilisation du formulaire émit par django par défaut)
class CustomSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser  # ici on spécifie qu'on veut ce modèle personnalisé
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        #note : le password est automatiquement intégré dans ce form


# view pour la page d'accueil
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'JoBooking/index.html')


# view pour la page des offres
def offres(request):
    list_offres = Offre.objects.all()  # affiche toutes les offres  = plan solo,duo,family ou autre
    context = {'offres': list_offres}
    return render(request, 'JoBooking/offres.html', context)


# view pour la page d'inscription
def inscription(request):
    context = {}  # stockage données  lors du rendu de page

    if request.method == 'POST':  # vérification methode de la requête est POST = formulaire soumis
        form = CustomSignupForm(request.POST)  # création formulaire avec données POST
        if form.is_valid():  # vérification  de la validité des données
            user = form.save()  # sauvegarde dans la BDD
            user.cle_inscription = uuid.uuid4().hex
            user.save()

            return redirect('inscription_reussie')  # redirection de l'utilisateur vers une autre page
        else:
            context['errors'] = form.errors  # erreur de validation

    form = CustomSignupForm()  # nouvelle page d'inscription vide  donc sans POST
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'JoBooking/inscription.html', context=context)  # renvoie page d'inscription


# view pour l'inscripion réussie d'un user
def inscription_reussie(request):
    return render(request, 'inscription_reussie.html')


# view pour la page de connexion
def connexion(request):
    message = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Connexion(request.POST)  # création formulaire avec données envoyées via POST
        if form.is_valid():  # vérification de la validité des données
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']  # données nettoyées et récupérées
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            custom_auth = EmailAuthBackend()  # implémentation de l'authentification personnalisée
            user = custom_auth.authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)  # appel de la méthode authenticate

            # email = request.POST.get('email')
            # password = request.POST.get('password')

            if user is not None and password is not None:  # signification : si l'user a été trouvée ...
                login(request, user, backend='JoBooking.authbackends.EmailAuthBackend')  # ya 2 backends d'auth
                message = f'Bienvenue {user.first_name} ! Vous êtes connecté.'
                return redirect('/')  # redirige vers la page d'acceuil
            else:
                message = 'Identifiants non valides.'
                return render(request, 'connexion.html',
                              context={'message': message})  # user non trouvé, donc retourne page connexion
    else:
        form = Connexion()

    return render(request, 'connexion.html', context={'form': form, 'message': message})


# méthode pour que les users se déconnecte
def deconnexion(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('index')


# méthode pour ajouter à réservation. ( réservation c'est le panier. J'ai volontairement choisi ce terme)
def ajouter_reservation(request, offre_id):
    user = request.user
    offre = get_object_or_404(Offre, id=offre_id)  # ici on récupère l'offre si inexistante,erreur 404
    reservation, _ = Reservation.objects.get_or_create(user=user)  # récupération du panier
    commande, created = Commande.objects.get_or_create(user=user,
                                                       offre=offre)  # récupération commande

    if created:  # exemple:  une offre n'est pas dans la commande donc elle sera crée
        reservation.commandes.add(commande)
        reservation.save()
    else:  # l'offre est deja dans la commande donc on augmente la quantité
        commande.quantity += 1
        commande.save()
    return redirect('offres')


#  renvoie  à la page de reservation (c'est la page panier, après avoir réserver)
@login_required(login_url='connexion')  # connexion nécessaire pour avoir accès a cette page
def reservation(request):
    reservation = get_object_or_404(Reservation, user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'reservation.html', context={
        'commandes': reservation.commandes.all()})  # affiche tous les éléments qu'ya dans la réservation


# methode pour annuler une réservation au complet
def annulation(request):
    user_reservation = Reservation.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if user_reservation:  # si elle existe
        user_reservation.commandes.all().delete()
        user_reservation.delete()  # suppression de tout ce qu'y a dans la réservation qu'on supprime ensuite

    return redirect('index')  # retourne vers la page d'accueil


def payer(request):
    reservation = request.user.reservation

    # génération de billets (combinaison des deux clés générées , qr code, nom acheteur + logo ;date de l'evement )

    # augmentation de ventes de Offre selon la quantité achetée
    for commande in reservation.commandes.all():
        offre = commande.offre  # récupration du plan dans la commande
        offre.ventes += commande.quantity
        offre.save()
    # paiement dans Reservation devient TRUE (initialement à FALSE)
    reservation.paiement = True
    reservation.save()

    # génération de clé unique pour paiment seulement si payer.
    if reservation.paiement == True:
        cle_paiement = uuid.uuid4().hex
        reservation.cle_paiement = cle_paiement
        reservation.save()

    # le panier (réservation ) est réinitialisé
    reservation.commandes.clear()
    # Renvoie à la page de remerciement où on peut telecharger billet
    return redirect('remerciements')


def remerciements(request):
    return render(request, 'remerciements.html')
```

'''

in test_views.py

'''

```
from django.test import TestCase
from ...JoBooking.models import CustomUser


class TestUrl(TestCase):
    def test_my_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

'''

another way to test

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis> python manage.py test JoBooking
Found 1 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: JoParis.JoBooking (unittest.loader._FailedTest.JoParis.JoBooking)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: JoParis.JoBooking
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\murhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 440, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\murhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 350, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoParis.JoBooking'
```

Comment: You should consider posting your code here for us to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: `from JoBookings.models import CustomUser`, no `JoParis`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.   
I have already done that. However, it indicates this error: Unresolved reference 'JoBooking'.

Comment: @kionaH: likely because you have set the source root at the wrong directory in the IDE.

Comment: As I said earlier, your post getting down votes due to lack of sufficient information about the issue. Post the Complete error message and related code.

Comment: `JoPari ` is the project name. You don't need it.

Comment: Where is `test_models.py ` is located?

Comment: C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis\JoBooking\tests\test_models.py

Comment: Then import statement should be as below.

Comment: `from JoBookings.models import CustomUser ` or `from ...JoBookings.models import CustomUser`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did what you just told me! The error "Unresolved reference 'JoBooking'" is not displayed, so the import is okay! But when I run my test... I still get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoParis.JoBooking'".    :'(

Comment: I would like to show you my code, but how can I do it? I'm new here.

Comment: I still get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoParis.JoBooking'"... I understand. Post the full console error output.

Answer (score 0):

**General answer :-**

Try like below.

```
from JoBookings.models import CustomUser
```

**You should use relative paths to import from other scripts.**
In `JoParis.JoBookings.models`

`JoParis` is the folder name/project name

`JoBookings` is the app name /app folder name(inside project folder)

`models` is the python file name(inside app folder).

Which all are relative to current (importing statement) file.

So, to import like above, `JoParis` should be a sub folder from the current test script.

---

**Insight upon new info regarding the problem :-**

For `C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis\JoBooking\tests\test_models.py` location, try like below.

```
from ...JoBookings.models import CustomUser
```

**More info :-**

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714063/13861187)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714647/13861187)

---

**Django tests :-**

[Look here for how to run tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests)

Comment: Exactly That's what I did... but when I try to run my test, I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "JoParis.JoBooking".

Comment: See my comment on your question.I will update my answer.

Comment: I did what you just told me! The error "Unresolved reference 'JoBooking'" is not displayed, so the import is okay! But when I run my test... I still get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoParis.JoBooking'". :'(

Comment: No. I told you to use dots to go up folder.

Comment: Like `from ...JoBookings.models import CustomUser `

Comment: See links on my answer.

Comment: It's not django specific. It's syntax in python.

Comment: i used dots  :
from ...JoBooking.models import CustomUser

Comment: Did it work correctly?

Comment: Yes  I have the green checkmark  ! The error "Unresolved reference 'JoBooking'" is not displayed, so the import is okay! But when I run my test... I still get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoParis.JoBooking

Comment: I have a question :   are there a link with the sys path ?

Comment: I have the impression that the module path is not found even though I imported correctly

Comment: Like I said before, help is limited due to, you not posting required code.

Comment: Nobody going to steal you code. Don't afraid to post relevant information, even 100+ lines of code.

Comment: That's not the issue, it's just that I don't know how to share it? I'm new here.

Comment: Copy the relevant code by selecting it and ctrl + c. Post the code in the question like ```code```.

Comment: Use ``` at both end of code.

Comment: Can you post full error message as well.

Comment: ok  ! you can see it  now

Comment: I get it now. Normally in django you should import model like below inside views.py. `from .models import DBmodelName` look in your views.py.

Comment: `from .models import CustomUser `

Comment: In test views. Use same as in test models. Like `from ...JoBookings.models import CustomUser`. I see you only changed test models.py. You need to change test views.py as well.

Comment: I did it .   I updated my post.   I have the same error

Comment: What? `from ...JoBooking.views import CustomUser ` is wrong in test_views.py. Use `from ...JoBooking.models import CustomUser`.

Comment: ah! my bad sorry! I modified with .models but there is still the same error... I know. I say it often but I try to understand.

Comment: i just updated my post with  the last error

Comment: So pytest command works? And `C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis> python manage.py test JoBooking` doesn't?

Comment: no ... :/   maybe  it's the settinsg or config   i don't know

Comment: C:\Users\murhe\PycharmProjects\StudiProject\JoParis> python manage.py test JoBooking doesn't?  the same  error   .      
add project path to sys path? is a solution? I saw this in some "solutions" I didn't do it because I'm not sure and I don't want to cause damage

Comment: Changing sys path is a bad solution. You should pass full dotted path. Not just your app name. Look here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: ok !  I did ./python manage.py test JoBooking.tests.TestCreateUser and also python manage.py test JoBooking.tests.TestCreateUser. Still, there's the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JoBooking.tests.TestCreateUser'. You know what. Thank you for your help and patience. I'm going to ask my teacher directly. I've been on it for a week. Thank you.